# How to make the input field to move up when data is being searched(like google) in angular

Tags: angular

how to make the input field move up when data is being searched in angular, like Google.com when we searched the data the input field goes up. for example

Before: [Before search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdluX.png)

After search: [After search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3POMB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's two different screens.

The first page has a search box center of the page.

The second page has a search box top of the page(In the navbar).

And pass search value in url params
`(like: ?q=test)`

So, Create an angular app with two screens. And pass your search value in URL params.(https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap)

[image]

Comment: can you give me code of angular to create this for simple input field